# Icon next to navigation title using Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, navigation, title

I would like to do that:

[image]

Concerning the right button, I did this:

```
let buttonRight = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
let textRight = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Mixte", style: .done, target: self, action: nil)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [textRight, buttonRight]
```

But I can't change the size of the image, and the click on the text is different than the click on the image (clicks are separated).

I would like to have only one click for both.

And now, for the title on the middle, I really don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To make both buttons execute the same method you need to add a selector.

```
    let buttonRight = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.doSomething(_:))
let textRight = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Mixte", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.doSomething(_:))

class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    func doSomething(_ sender: AnyObject){
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work... When I click on the texte for example, the color change only on the texte, and the same for the icon :/